# How does the Container Node in the Title Bar of the Application Layout Control work? (added code)

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I created a Layout Control that uses the ExtLib Application Layout Control.  I have several Title Bar items, of which one is a Container Node.  The Container Node has several children. The problem is when I put this on an XPage and run it, the child nodes don't show up.  In fact, the cursor does not change to the pointing finger when it is over the Container Node either.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there something else to configure?

```
<xe:basicContainerNode
label="Information Centers">
<xe:this.children>
    <xe:basicLeafNode
    label="Account Requirements"
    href="https://Server.xxx.com/Support and Info/acctreq.nsf?OpenDatabase">
        </xe:basicLeafNode>
</xe:this.children>
</xe:basicContainerNode>
```

MJ

Comment: Paste your code - code talks!

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but I think title bar will only display tabs, which are a one level only item (can't have children).

I have some code that reads documents that control the displayed tabs(title, link ...) if you are interrested. I am not quite sure this is what you want to do though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks to me like the Banner Bar Containers work differently than the Title Bar Containers.  I can get the Banner Bar Containers to work properly, but not so with the Title bar containers.  Does anyone no why this is the case?

MJ